# Rails 3.0 Mongrel issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongrel

Ok guys the truth is I'm working on porting an application up to justhost.com as I cant afford my own servers yet. Either way I have been receiving this error in the mongrel.log and am getting no help as to what this error means or how to fix it.

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': no such file to load -- dispatcher (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in`require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in`new_constants_in'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in`require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:148:in `rails'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:113:in`cloaker_'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:149:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:149:in`listener'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:99:in `cloaker_'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:50:in`call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:50:in `initialize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:84:in`new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:84:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/command.rb:212:in`run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:281
    from /usr/bin/mongrel_rails:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/mongrel_rails:19

I don't think this is anything dealing with the setup of my application, but I'm also a bit of a newb to Rails. If anyone knows how to fix this or what I may have done wrong, I'd appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some looking into this one. As JustHost uses cPanel it turns out that cPanel currently does not support Rails 3.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're still interested in an answer but I had the same error when I was trying to start mongrel with the command mongrel_rails start in my rails3 app.

But it worked when I started it with rails server in the script folder of your app. If the mongrel gem is in your Gemfile, running rails server will start Mongrel and not WEBrick.

You'll find more information [here](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/browse_thread/thread/88b3f13f956ea1ed/3cf93bc20dcb79a1).

Hope this helps !

Johan